# Porting from Google App Engine to Amazon

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

Right now our application is running on Google App Engine and we want to migrate to Amazon. 
We are mainly thinking of cost optimization (as we feel app engine is so costly) and hence we decide to take this step.
Secondly there are limitations on App Engine where only limited resources we can use.

As we made up our mind to move to Amazon and I need some technical help.

1. Any good alternative for appengine datastore? We are planning to use Dynamodb but it has limitation of 64KB entity size. Our datastore entities are bigger in size (more than 1 mb and we store them as shards). We are thinking to use S3 for that. Is Dynamodb + S3 is good?
2. Any alternative for Task Queues? Sometimes we required to schedule task to run after 30 days.
3. We are using long (not String) auto generated ids. So any good service which guarantees unique ids in distributed system.
4. As our application is big (more than 5 million users and large number of active users), we don't want to go with downtime. The migration should happen seamlessly without making our users to aware of it. We are thinking of doing migration when user logs in but apart from this any idea/approach would be a great help.
5. Even we want to know how we can manage our existing entity ids while migration.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it covers too many subjects; it is too broad; some aspects (your migration strategy) do not fit well with the Q&A format and may require expertise specific to your deployment; other aspects (reommending "alternatives" and "any good service") are primarily opinion-based, have too many possible answers, and seem inconsistent with the scope of the site. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/

Answer (score 1):

Look at open source editions of Google App Engine : http://www.appscale.com/ & https://github.com/AppScale/appscale/wiki

Answer (score 0):

If you want to minimize recoding, you might look in to http://www.jboss.org/capedwarf , which is supports a large subset of the App Engine APIs atop the JBoss Application Server. I've not used it myself, but we've worked with them on a compatibility test suite.